# How to code a counter which loops within an interval in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, counter, countdowntimer, delayed-execution

I am trying to build a countdown view inside an Android App with Kotlin. The code that I currently have crashes the app while running.

PS: Integer `timer` should be altered later on the application as well.

```
var timer:  Int = 50  // Declared globally
private fun timer(){
        timer_text.text = timer.toString()    // Text view in UI

        while (timer > 1){
            Handler().postDelayed({
                timer--
                timer_text.text = timer.toString()   // Update the Text view in UI
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
```

Logcat

```
I/sandaru.projec: Thread[6,tid=11100,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb400007b3dcd9f50,peer=0x13280238,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/sandaru.projec: 
I/sandaru.projec: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=5.51ms min=1.98ms max=10.47ms count=60
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: It just crashes the app.

Comment: please post the error from the logcat?

Comment: add it in the question

Comment: `while` is an (almost) infinite loop. You probably wanted to do something like: replace `while` with `if` and invoke `timer()` from inside `postDelayed()`>

Comment: why is using `CountDownTimer` not an option here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an ANR, since you are executing the while loop on main thread, you can try with below code, doing this will suspend instead of blocking

```
var timer:  Int = 50  // Declared globally
private suspend fun timer(){
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        timer_text.text = timer.toString()    // Text view in UI

        while (timer > 1){               
            timer--
            timer_text.text = timer.toString()   // Update the Text view in UI
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
}
```

and you need to execute the code from inside a coroutine, for ex. in the activity/fragment you can execute like this

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    timer()        
}
```

Comment: ```Unresolved reference: lifecycleScope``` Gives this error

Comment: @SandaruMuthuwadige you can add this dependency ->`implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'`, or you can use `CoroutineScope().launch` instead of `lifecycleScope.launch` if coroutines dependency was added, but it is not recommended